# How can I ask for a review of the same item after making an update?

Tags: discussion, iterative-review

Suppose, I submit a code for review, and some reviewers suggest some corrections. Suppose I then want to update my code and show it to the same reviewers.

How should I do it? Should I edit my previous question, or, should I ask a new question?

Comment: Also see: [How to post a follow-up question?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/how-to-post-a-follow-up-question)

Answer (score 1):

When you've asked a question, had feedback, made changes, and are ready for another review,

**You should post a new question with the updated code**, but, link the original review, just for clarity.

For example, user [@QPaysTaxes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/62850/qpaystaxes), has a trilogy of questions relating to a BF to Ruby converter,

And for each, they write a new question:

[Number 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94489/brainfk-to-ruby-converter-written-in-ruby-v1-0), [Number 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94520/brainfk-to-ruby-converter-v2) and [Number 3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94596/brainfk-to-ruby-interpreter-v3).

Because your original code is different to the code adjusted with the review in mind, it's different code, meaning it deserves a different review.